# Are there subtile differences between one and multiline if expressions in Julia?

Tags: julia

I am using Julia 1.1.1 and discovered something interesting yesterday.

Minimal example below

Consider the following code:

```
julia> if ((true)) true else false end
true
```

Works as intended

However, when attempting to do the following:

```
julia> function foo()
         true
       end
foo (generic function with 1 method)
julia> if ((foo())) (true,false) else (false,true) end
ERROR: syntax: space before "(" not allowed in "foo() ("
julia>
```

However, when writing the expression in the standard way it seems to work

```
julia> if ((foo()))
         (true, false)
       else
         false
       end
(true, false)

julia>
```

From my understanding from the following post [Does Julia have a ternary conditional operator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39790031/does-julia-have-a-ternary-conditional-operator) I should be allowed to write if expressions in much the same way as ternaries and I usually can. However, for this case the ternary operator seems to be working as intended but not the if expression

```
julia>  ((foo())) ? (true,false) : (false,true)
(true, false)
```

Does it exists a subtile difference between the two?

As noted in the comments by crstnbr the following syntax is allowed:

```
if ((foo())) true,false else false,true end
```

Comment: Note that `if ((foo())) true,false else false,true end` works.

Comment: Noted! Thanks :) I should change my title when returning tuples with parenthesis? Would subtle differences between one line if expressions and multiline work for you?

Comment: I would add that, syntactical curiosity aside, I consider it very bad style (let alone idea) to write that one-liner without appropriately terminating the different statements. This is entirely more readable (and completely obviates the use of ugly parentheses): `if true; true, false; else; false, true; end`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This does not seem to have anything to do with the if block per se. It is simply a syntax error.

Effectively, julia prohibits the syntax `myfun (args)` when calling a function (i.e. no space is allowed between the function name and the parentheses).

Since the output of a function, e.g., in this case `foo()`, may be another function, the same rule must apply to returned arguments. You wrapping your `foo()` function in infinite parentheses does nothing to resolve this, since the output of that expression is still asked to be evaluated via wrong syntax.

For example, note that:

```
julia> foo()()
ERROR: MethodError: objects of type Bool are not callable
Stacktrace:
[1] top-level scope at none:0
```

whereas

```
julia> foo() ()
ERROR: syntax: space before "(" not allowed in "foo() ("
```

Furthermore, as I mentioned in my comment above, regardless of the above, I personally would consider such terse `if` blocks very bad style, as well as a bad idea, as you have yourself just figured out. If you don't want to split into lines, it's is still a good idea, and much more readable, to use a semicolon at the end of the appropriate statements to show clear separation (both to yourself reading the code, and to the interpreter).

i.e.

```
if true; true, false; else; false, true; end
if foo(); true, false; else; false, true; end
```

Comment: Excellent answer! For this corner case, the \n in the multiline example resolves the issue in this case, it works much as you demonstrated with the semicolons no? I agree with you, the reason I ran into this issue is that I am writing a transpiler that translates from language X into Julia thus the original code was something that my transpiler generated. It surprised me a little bit

Comment: Yes, in general a newline used for terminating a statement will act the same as a semicolon and vice versa. Obviously newlines can be used in non-terminating contexts too, in which case substituting with a semicolon will probably not be appropriate.