# Julia, for loop iterator increase to zero

Tags: for-loop, iterator, julia

I have a nice function that sums a group of random numbers generated with this function.

```
sum(round(Int8, floor(
        rand(TruncatedNormal(var1, var2, var3, var4))))
                     for _ in 1:var5)
```

Most of the time it works fine, var5, the iterator for the `for` loop is calculated earlier in a function, and can legitimately be a zero.  Therefore iterating by increasing from 1 to 0 doesn't work and throws an error.  Is there a clean "check" in Julia that will simply produce a result of 0 for the whole function, or do I need to go back and enclose this function in an `if` statement to check the value of var5 prior to running it, and if `var5<=0`, produce an alternate result (0)?  Thx. J

Comment: Have you tried the options suggested in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39790031/does-julia-have-a-ternary-conditional-operator)?

Comment: Thx. PaSTE, I can see the ternary operator is elegant and simple, I just can't get it to work with this code, could you show a suggested syntax for the code?

Answer (score 5):

When you do `sum(rand(Int8) for _ in 1:0)` you get the error:

```
julia> sum(rand(Int8) for x in 1:0)
ERROR: ArgumentError: reducing over an empty collection is not allowed
Stacktrace:
 [1] _empty_reduce_error() at ./reduce.jl:299
 [2] mapreduce_empty(::Function, ::Base.BottomRF{typeof(Base.add_sum)}, ::Type{T} where T) at ./reduce.jl:342
 [3] reduce_empty(::Base.MappingRF{var"#9#10",Base.BottomRF{typeof(Base.add_sum)}}, ::Type{Int64}) at ./reduce.jl:329
 [4] reduce_empty_iter at ./reduce.jl:355 [inlined]
 [5] reduce_empty_iter at ./reduce.jl:354 [inlined]
 [6] foldl_impl at ./reduce.jl:49 [inlined]
 [7] mapfoldl_impl at ./reduce.jl:44 [inlined]
 [8] #mapfoldl#204 at ./reduce.jl:160 [inlined]
 [9] mapfoldl at ./reduce.jl:160 [inlined]
 [10] #mapreduce#208 at ./reduce.jl:287 [inlined]
 [11] mapreduce at ./reduce.jl:287 [inlined]
 [12] sum at ./reduce.jl:494 [inlined]
 [13] sum(::Base.Generator{UnitRange{Int64},var"#9#10"}) at ./reduce.jl:511
 [14] top-level scope at REPL[6]:1
```

One very simple workaround is to collect the random numbers into an array first — or simply use a comprehension instead of a generator:

```
julia> sum([rand(Int8) for x in 1:0])
0
```

You could also use the ternary expression as linked above to simply avoid the problem altogether:

```
julia> var5 = 0
0

julia> var5 < 1 ? 0 : sum(rand(Int8) for x in 1:var5)
0

julia> var5 = 2
2

julia> var5 < 1 ? 0 : sum(rand(Int8) for x in 1:var5)
49
```

Comment: And it just that easy!  Thx. J

Answer (score 3):

For cases where you need to catch the case of summing over an empty collection, I prefer an explicit `reduce` with an `init` value:

```
julia> reduce(+, (rand(Int8) for x in 1:0), init=Int8(0))
0
```

Comment: Very nice elegant solution. Thx. J

Comment: it should be `init=Int8(0)` so if the result should be a `Int8` too