# Hi, what does the following line in Julia do? Thank you

Tags: julia

H = H === nothing ? h : [H h]
#both matrices

Comment: Possible dupe: https://stackoverflow.com/q/39790031/2602718

Comment: This is a totally valid question by a Julia newbie. I do not understand negative votes. Vote to reopen it.

Answer (score 3):

The matrix `H` is being assigned a value based on a [ternary operator](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/control-flow/), which takes the form `a ? b : c`. In this case, if `H` is `nothing`, it will made the same as `h`. Otherwise, it will be concatenated with `h` (as with `hcat`).

**Note**: When `H === nothing`, the code does *not* assign `H` the values of `h`, as has been suggested. Instead, `H` is a *copy* of `h`. For instance, if you change one of the elements in `H`, it will change an element in `h`, since they are **the same matrix**.

It may help to look at the [documentation for arrays](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/arrays/).

Answer (score 1):

Suppose

```
H === nothing
```

evaluates to true, then H is assigned the value of h. If false, then H is assigned to a 1x2 matrix which has H as its first value and h as its second value.